# Do all (most) frequencies of UV cause sunburn?

Tags: radiation

I recently read in a book called “The universe in your hand” that the reason you can get hurt by ionizing radiation is that the photons carry enough energy to ionize an atom, which can cause chemical reactions to happen, thus causing reactions to the radiation in different ways. But to my knowledge only higher frequencies of UV light are ionizing. Does this mean that only these frequencies cause sunburn, or that the other causes sunburn in some other way?